# Will Apple TV work if I connected it to a DVD player?

Tags: appletv

My TV does not have an HDMI input, so I was wondering if I could still use it by connecing the Apple TV to my DVD player's HDMI port instead?

My DVD player ([Philips DVP3560/F7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003LWXJ2A)) is capable of 1080p.

Also, will Apple TV work with my (rather old) TV? My TV ([Samsung TXN2668WHF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000A3I49Q)) is capable of **1080i** and 480p.

Comment: The DVD-players HDMI port is most likely for _output_, not input.

Answer (score 1):

The apple TV 2 supports 480p. In my case it works through my AV/Amplifier which is connected with an HDMI cable to my TV.

The only catch would be HDCP which requires end to end protection of data. But from what I understand HDCP allows non HDCP compliant hardware to receive lower quality image using legacy connectors (RCA, S-Video ...). So it all depends on how your DVD player is connected to the TV.

Comment: My DVD player will be connected to the TV through an RCA connector. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) Will that work? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: In this case it "should" work. Although it will really depend on our DVD player and the way it manages the input and output signals. The only way to make sure is to try... You could ask at your local apple store. And worse case scenario bring the apple TV back if it doesn't work. I can't test on my TV, I don't have any RCA cables at hand. I might try this week once I find some (and if my AV/Amp supports RCA, not sure about that).

Comment: Yup. I will be sure to give it a try. (I haven't bought the DVD player yet) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Apple TV so I've been through the setup using an A/V receiver.  If you wish to keep the TV you have, you need an A/V receiver instead of regular DVD player.

Apple TV2 outputs HDMI and the device it connects to will need HDMI inputs.  I have a one year old Panasonic BluRay player plus a Sony progressive scan DVD player and neither supports HDMI inputs.  If you can find a DVD player with an HDMI input, it is probably a combination A/V receiver and DVD player.

If connecting the Apple TV2 is your goal, look to an A/V receiver.  You may find a receiver that also plays DVDs if you also want to play DVDs.

Apple TV2 now supports 720P which is better video than the RCA jacks can support.  The good news is your TV supports component video which is a better way than using the RCA port for video.  To use the component ports, you'll need component cables which are a step up from the RCA composite cables.  For audio, you will need to use the composite RCA audio ports but at least you'll be watching an HD quality picture.

Answer (score 0):

Highly doubtful.  A $50 DVD player with a single HDMI port is almost certainly an HDMI-output port only.

If you don't want to buy an A/V receiver or a new TV, you can buy a standalone HDMI-to-component decoder.  They seem to run $30 to $40.